# Why doesn't the "More->Create Event" menu item in Gmail populate the calendar event with info?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

Whenever I choose Create Event, it just pops up a calendar window with the date set to today and the title set to untitled event.  This used to fill in info from the message (at the very least the title).